# Setting Up Windows Push Notification Services (WNS) Server Side

Tags: windows, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to set up Windows Push Notification Services (WNS) for Windows server 2013.  But I can't seem to find any documentation regarding this online, as most of it just explained more towards the client side.

Any guidance or reference is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanted to do push notification service for Windows, then you're correct that windows notification service is the right one. However it is a  cloud notification service just like Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) or Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). However you can host your own service in Windows Server 2013 to talk to WNS. Otherwise you can use Azure Notification Hub which can integrate with your backend. So if you go for [Azure Notification Hub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj927170.aspx), you will need to build a backend that talks to to Azure. Take a look at the link

Comment: Thanks for Azure notification hub link, helped me to get the WNS to work.